# reading unicode text file in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, file, unicode

I have file contained `"Hindi" "marathi"` texts which comes under `devnagari script`.  I have to read this `unicode` contained file in ios application. I tried normal text file reading code with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding, but it returns `nil`. then i tried `NSUTF32StringEncoding`,it agains returned `nil`.

I googled for it, but i got solutions to show hindi,marathi font on label or textview, textfileld by using specific font. but here i have to read file having hindi fonts.

please let me know what are the ways to implement it.

text looks like this-प्रेम शब्द फक्त दोन अक्षरांचा,  नुसता ऐकला तर हर्श होतो,  आणि ऊच्चारला तर दोन ओठांमधे स्पर्श होतो.

Comment: What about using `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`? It treats characters as UTF-16.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual file?

Comment: @KyokookHwang:No its not working with NSUnicodeStringEncoding

Comment: This is text:प्रेम शब्द फक्त दोन अक्षरांचा,  नुसता ऐकला तर हर्श होतो,  आणि ऊच्चारला तर दोन ओठांमधे स्पर्श होतो.